# Default Activity Not Found with two different dimensions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, huawei-developers

I needed to use two different dimensions in the project. But after this usage, whatever I do, Android Studio tells me "Default Activity Not Found". Actually there's no changes in the src folder because I don't need to modify any classes in the flavors.

```
flavorDimensions "device", "backend"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_VERSION", "\"1.1\""
        ...extra configs
        dimension "backend"
    }
    staging {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_VERSION", "\"1.1\""
        ...extra configs
        dimension "backend"
    }
    prod {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_VERSION", "\"1.1\""
        ...extra configs
        dimension "backend"
    }
    android {
        buildConfigField "String", "DEVICE_TYPE", "\"ANDROID\""
        dimension "device"
    }
    huawei {
        buildConfigField "String", "DEVICE_TYPE", "\"ANDROID_HW\""
        versionCode 10000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        dimension "device"
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name=".XApplication"
    ...

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Try to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... android studio. If still not working you need to check manifest for once. Can you share main intent filter form your manifest file?

Comment: I've tried to make invalidate caches & restart, but it's still same. Shared the manifest.

Comment: It is looking fine in manifest file. Is everything is working fine without product flavor? If yes, Have you tried to clear your project?

Comment: Tried everything. I expect to see it's working properly but not. Somehow flavor system needs default activity in their folder I guess. But it's absolutely nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, change the `android:name` attribute of your activity to the fully-qualified class name of your Activity, instead of using the `.ui.SplashActivity` notation. When you prefix the name with `.`, it will append that to the `package` annotation of your `<manifest>` attribute, which may or may not match the package of your actual Activity class. Make sure your Activity class has the correct `package` declaration at the top of the file and is located in the right src directory.

The same goes for your Application class name. I avoid using the `.` notation at all costs.

Comment: Take a look at your Manifest file in "Merged Manifest" mode (tab at the bottom) and make sure the Activity is actually present. Or, it sounds like your Run Configuration could be corrupted somehow. Go to Run -> Edit Configurations and make sure you have the right module selected for the configuration you're trying to run.